# How read file line by line if I don't know the number of fields?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

`filename.csv` contains:

```
public|database|subs_vw|5|6|9|3|10|1
```

Basically my script is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function replace_col(){
    prep_cmd="awk -F\| 'BEGIN {srand()}
                            {sub(\$$1,\"Sa\"int(rand()*100000)\"GA\"); print}' \
                            $tablename.data > $tablename.ano"
    echo $prep_cmd
    eval $prep_cmd
}

tablename="subs_vw"

gawk 'BEGIN {FS="|"}
      { for(i=4;i<=NF;i++)
        var="echo $i"
        echo $var
        replace_col $i
      }' < filename.csv
```

Giving file as input it takes value correct but is not calling a function. Basically I want replace all specified columns e.g. 5|6|9|3|10|1 by a random number. Can anybody help me out please?

Comment: Note that an `awk` script cannot execute a shell function (for all practical purpose; it might be able to get a shell to run a shell function, but that's where ShellShock found its target).

Answer (score 2):

A simple `for` loop can serve the purpose.

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FS="|"}
            { print "SCHEMA :" $1
              print "DATABASE :" $2
              print "TABLENAME :" $3
              for(i=4;i<=NF;i++)
                   print "COLUMN :" $i

             }' filename.txt
```

Here `NF` is number of fields, columns in each row.

`for(i=4;i<=NF;i++)`

will iterate from the 4th column to the end of the columns.

EDIT

Replacing `|5|6|9|3|10|1` with random numbers.

```
 awk -F\| '{OFS = "|";for(i=4;i<NF;i++) $i= int(rand()*100); print $0 }' inputfile
```

Will produce an ouput as

`public|database|subs_vw|23|29|84|15|58|1`

what it does

`$i= int(rand()*100)` the ith field is replaced by a random number.

`rand()` returns a random number within `0` and `1`

`int()` truncates the value to integer

`print $0` prints the entire record.

EDIT2

change `5 6 9 10` to random values

```
 $awk -F\| 'BEGIN{OFS = "|"; indx[1]=5; indx[2]=6; indx[3]=9; indx[4]=10 }{for(i in indx) if(indx[i]<=NF)  $indx[i]=int(rand()*100); print $0 }' file
    public|database|subs_vw|5|29|84|3|10|15|23
```

Comment: can you please look above question i have made some changes to it can you please suggest it now

Comment: @AshishTripurwar i didnt get what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @AshishTripurwar i made an edit. hopes that this is what you expect. any feedback is apreciated

Comment: but it will changing values for 4 to 10 i mean all the columns from i=4 to NF i don't want replace all of them just 5 6 9 10 etc

Comment: is there some pattern?? how will i know which column to replace?

Comment: i have read it from conf file which will contain public|database|subs_vw|3|9|4|5|8|1 and lot more lines like this

Comment: @AshishTripurwar how is it now?

Comment: it's fantastic but i don't know what number of columns will be there may only 1 column to replace in table and 5 columns for next table

Comment: vaules in front of indx[1] should be read from file not directly 5 6 like this.

Comment: i assumed that the file contains a line `public|database|subs_vw|5|29|84|3|10|15|23` so is the output like that. Or give an input file and expected output

Comment: question is not clear. `5` is read from the same file? if so which line contains the value 5. or for each line reaplace the column in  5|6|9|3|10|1 by a random number?

Comment: no it's another file which has tablename and column names only

Comment: shouldn't you be specifiying that too in the question? please edit the question to include relevent information. along with an input file and your expected output